# NSNumber Formatting (Round to 1000's place)

Tags: objective-c

I currently have a series of NSNumber objects with values between 0 and 500,000. They are randomly generated values with many decimal places.

How can I print these values, but round them to the nearest 1000? For example 32143.8472 would round to 32000. For simplicity, lets assume I want them in a NSLog...

eg.

```
NSLog(@"The number is: %@", WHATGOESHERE??)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NSNumber objects are suitable for storing values, for numeric operations you should use plain numeric types (e.g. int)

Try the following code:

```
int rounded = 1000*(([number intValue]+500)/1000);
```

What happens there:

1. `[number intValue]`
   That gets integer part of our number
2. add 500 and divide by 1000 - get the nearest number of thousands in our number
3. Multiply by 1000 - compensate for previous division to get a number actually rounded to the thousands

And log it if you want:

```
NSLog(@"The number is: %d", rounded)
```